# Queens Puzzle Breadth first

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, n-queens

I've been told to make a program that solves the [eight queens puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) using [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). This is what i've got so far:

```
def n_queens(n, width):
if n == 0:
    return [[]
else:
    return add_queen(n-1, width, n_queens(n-1, width))


def add_queen(new_row, width, previous_solutions):
solutions = []
for sol in previous_solutions:
    for new_col in range(width):
        if safe_queen(new_row, new_col, sol):
            solutions.append(sol + [new_col])
return solutions


def safe_queen(new_row, new_col, sol):
for row in range(new_row):
    if (sol[row] == new_col or                  
        sol[row] + row == new_col + new_row or
        sol[row] - row == new_col - new_row):
            return 0
return 1

for sol in n_queens(8, 8):
print sol
```

Is there any way to improve this?

Comment: One obvious improvement would be to make it work. This code doesn't work. The first obvious bug is that the `n_queens` recursion has no base case.

Comment: That seems to be the only bug, though. After putting in a base case `if not n: return [[]]`, the code produces expected results.

Comment: BFS isn't usually implemented recursively anyway, but iteratively. It just requires you to use a deque (double-ended queue), add children to the end of the queue and pop them off the front.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I've never used deque before. Can you give me an example of it being used in this scenario?

Comment: You iterate through the "adjacent" nodes/next steps and, if they haven't been seen before, add them to the end of the queue. When you're done checking all the adjacent nodes/next steps from the current step, remove the current step currently at the head/start of the queue, then BFS on the next step in the queue/new head.

Comment: @KyleSum Thank you. I'm just having a bit of difficulty implementing it in code; i've just started learning programming on my own.

Comment: This requires tricky recursion for someone at your level. It could very well be an interview problem for prospective interns in the tech industry.  Dont feel bad if you cant get it, but I would encourage you to tackle easier projects first, especially if my answer below doesnt make sense.

Comment: @kylesum Thank you for your advice. I'm going to try and get my head round it otherwise it'll be constantly on my mind. I've been searching for a solution on google just so I can grasp the code but i cant find any!

Comment: Dont just look up the answer no matter how tempting it may be. First read my answer below and get out a piece of paper. Sketch out the approach. What are you trying to solve? What does that entail? Think about how to place queens and how one decision affects the next. If youre still lost, try to read explanations in english and implement it on your own. Recursion is important, and the sooner you start coding recursively the better off youll be in the future.

Comment: Tip: Python is supposed to be more convenient to test because, for example, it doesn't need to recompile. You should use this to your advantage by testing parts often. Also, look up breadth first search animations and stuff about game graphs. You need an image in your head about the problem as a graph: BFS is a graph search algorithm.

Comment: Cheers guys. Gonna keep working at it ;)

Comment: Are you cheating on your assignment? It very much sounds like it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think BFS is quite the way I'd reason about this problem. Rather, focus on recursively generating the possible placements. For each queen placed, there are only a certain number of possible placements in next row down that can't be attacked. "Place" a queen and recurse on each of those locations, and terminate when you've placed your total number of queens. Hopefully you'll recognize that a for loop mixed in with some recursive calls seems to be like a decent idea. Also remember to "pick up" the queens you placed as your recursion returns.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with previous entry. The algorithm described above is 'depth-first' search instead of 'breadth-first' search and is much more efficient for this type of problems.